# HTTP server that handles requests through IO devices?

Tags: http, iostream

This question can probably only be answered for Unix-like systems that follow the "everything is a file" idiom.

Would it be hard to create a web server that mounts local devices for handling http traffic? It would enable a program to read raw http requests from `/dev/httpin` (for example) and write the responses to `/dev/httpout`. I think this would be nice because it would allow me to create a http handler from any programming language that is capable of handling IO streams.

I don't really know where to start on this. Any suggestions on how to setup such a system?

Comment: this way leads to CGI...

Comment: In any case, you should access the same device for both input and output. Otherwise, how would you know which response belongs to which request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Javier, check out standards such as [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/), [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/files/SPEC.html), [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/), or the inchoate [OWIN](http://owin.github.com/). These interfaces exist basically so that disparate software components can exchange HTTP messages on the same machine, without using network sockets.

Personally, if I was looking to do this, I'd use my favorite JVM library, [Restlet](http://restlet.org) (probably with [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) or [Jython](http://jython.org)) and implement a custom `ServerConnector` which would construct a `Request` object and then pass it off to the rest of the framework. This sort of flexibility of architecture is why I like Restlet.